# Авторизация через вк, используя passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, вконтакте, auth, passport

Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию пользователя на сейте через соц. сеть ВК. Выдает ошибку: [image: ошибка]. Как её исправить? или как правильно реализовать эту функцию?

passport.js:

```
var vkStrategy = configAuth.vkAuth;
var User = require('../app/models/user');

vkStrategy.passReqToCallback = true; // проверет, вошел ли пользователь в систему или нет
passport.use(new VKStrategy(vkStrategy,
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
        //     function (req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // ассинхронность
        process.nextTick(function() {
            // проверка существования логина
            if (!req.user) {
                User.findOrCreate({
                    vkontakteId: profile.id
                }, function(err, user) {
                    //   User.findOne({'vkontakte.id': profile.id}, function (err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    if (user) {
                        if (!user.vkontakte.token) {
                            user.vkontakte.token = token;
                            user.vkontakte.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                            user.vkontakte.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();

                            user.save(function(err) {
                                if (err)
                                    return done(err);
                                return done(null, user);
                            });
                        }
                        return done(null, user); //если пользователь найден
                    } else {
                        // если нет, создаем нового
                        var newUser = new User();

                        newUser.vkontakte.id = profile.id;
                        newUser.vkontakte.token = token;
                        newUser.vkontakte.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                        newUser.vkontakte.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();

                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                return done(err);
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // пользователь существует и вошел в систему, аккаунты связываются
                var user = req.user;

                user.vkontakte.id = profile.id;
                user.vkontakte.token = token;
                user.vkontakte.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                user.vkontakte.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        });

    }));
```

auth.js:

```
module.exports = {
    'vkAuth': {
        'lang': 'ru',
        'clientID'  : '###',
        'clientSecret' : '#######',
        'callbackURL' : 'http://localhost:8080/auth/vkontakte/callback',
        'profileFields' : ['id', 'email', 'name']
    }
}
```

user.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   vkontakte        : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вы модель User хоть подключили ?

Comment: @ube42. Да, отредактирвала пост

Answer (score 0):

Не могу комментарий оставить.. нехватает репы, поэтому ответом.  
С чего Вы взяли, что функция `findOrCreate()` есть в `VK API`? 
Как выйти из этой ситуации сейчас: просто замените `findOrCreate()` на `findOne()` и обрабатывайте результат так. 
Либо можно использовать библиотеку: https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate

Comment: заменила на  findOne, теперь выдает ошибку `ReferenceError: token is not defined`

Comment: Приложите stacktrace ошибки

Answer (score 0):

В пакете Mongoose отсутствует `findOrCreate`

Решение:

1) Установить пакет mongoose-findorcreate:
`npm i mongoose-findorcreate`

2) После определения схемы добавить плагин:
`userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate)`

После этого данной ошибки быть не должно